# How could one approximate a flat piecewise function using trigonometric identities?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, piecewise-continuity, step-function

I have a flat piecewise function that is `a` on the interval $-L<x<L$, and 0 outside of this boundary. Perhaps $a=1/(2L)$, or perhaps not. However, I am looking to approximate this with a continuous function, very preferably made of a combination (i.e. sum) of trigonometric identities. I have looked at other answers, but they either have a single step, rather than a rectangular interval, and don't seem to use trig identities to approximate this flat piecewise interval (where by flat, I mean constant over the interval). When I try to do this myself, I tend to get a quickly repeating function (i.e. not just one flat interval), and--more prominently--the interval isn't approximately flat. Could someone help me out, please?

My apologies for adding more constraints after the fact, but it turns out that this function should also be normalizable for what i'd be using it for.

And, in order to make this more feasible, this function should be within a larger interval $-a<x<a$, where $a>L$. For reference, I'm looking for an approximation of a rectangular shape (the piecewise constant function) inside of a larger, finite interval. Can someone help me out, please? Can such a function be reasonably constructed?

Comment: You mean a Fourier Series?

Comment: Fourier series will give a periodic function.  You could use a Fourier integral, but the representation (inverse integral) will not be a sum.

Comment: Some sort of function like $f(x)=-1+\exp\left(\frac{1}{\lambda+x^{2n}}\right)$ isn't too bad

Comment: What is $a?$ Does “flat” mean linear? Or a step function?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. By flat, I meant constant, like a step function. And ideally, I'm trying to make this approximation out of a sum of sin/cos waves and such.

Comment: And K.defaoite's function is a good approximation itself, with high enough n. That might be a very good approximation for my problem. However, it would be more ideal if I can make it out of trig waves, application-wise.

Comment: My apologies for adding extra constraints, but it turns out for what i'm using this for the function should be normalizable, which is not true of K.defaoite's function. Otherwise, it looks great and makes a great approximation for the piecewise function, which is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this the kind of solution the OP is looking for. As required, we choose a function that is zero outside of the interval $(-L, L)$. Inside we choose a flat function, i.e. a constant $C$, in the smaller interval $(-K,K)$. We then connect the three regions by means of cosine functions.

$x \le -L$: $$f(x) = 0$$
$-L \le x \le -K$: $$f(x) = (C/2) * [1 - cos(\frac {\pi (L+x)} {L-K}) ]$$
$-K \le x \le K$: $$f(x) = C$$
$K \le x \le L$: $$f(x) = (C/2)*[1 - cos(\frac {\pi (L-x)} {L-K}]$$
$L \le x$: $$f(x) = 0$$

This is a piece-wise continous representation, as requested. The function and its first derivative are continuous. Note that one can choose the  central region to be broad, by setting e.g. $K = 0.95 L$. Then the two transition regions are narrow. Or the flat region can be small or absent ($K = 0$).

Comment: Yeah, this is great! However, I was looking for one continuous function to approximate the piecewise function. For instance, something that one can find the derivative of. I do appreciate this, though!

Comment: Such continuous functions exist, but they do not have a flat region inside and they can not be expressed in sines and cosines. So in the end, it is up to you to make a choice.

Comment: Alright, that's fair. Could such a continuous function be created to be somewhat flat inside without sines or cosines (that would work for what i'd be using it for, it's just less ideal)? Perhaps something like what K.defaoite suggested above, but normalizable?

Comment: Yes. There are many choices for such a function.

Comment: Oh alright, that seems useful. What are some functions that could fit this description?

Comment: A simple one is $f(x) = 2 - (n+2)x^n + nx^{n+2}$ with $-1 < x < 1$. Take a large enough even value for $n$, e.g. $n = 8$. And you get a block shape with rounded edges.

Comment: Actually, could you please give some examples and such as an answer? Maybe along the lines of 'You can't do that, but these would work as such an approximation, because...'? I think that would fullfill the requirements for what I need, and would really help others as a correct answer.
As for the approximation you just gave, it's the right shape, but it would be better if it had the flat space outside of the rectangle, and could sustain beyond 1 to some a greater than the edges of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Trig functions are periodic, so any approximation with trig functions will be periodic. Your function (considered as a function on the complete real line) is not periodic. On what interval are you trying to approximate this function? If you want to approximate this (non-periodic) function on the whole real line, trig functions won’t work. If you want to approximate it on some specific interval $I$ larger than $(-L,L)$, you can use trig functions (Fourier Series), which will approximate your function’s periodic extension from $I$ to the whole real line.

Comment: Alright, so, if I have this function step function within a given interval (-I/2, I/2), I could create this approximation out of waves? How would one go about actually creating it, given the conditions?

Comment: Google or find videos or books on “Fourier series approximation.”